# Redirect after multi-tenant SSO login in Pentaho with spring-SAML

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, pentaho, multi-tenant, spring-saml

I would like to configure Pentaho with a multi-tenant SSO login using the SAML Plugin [Link](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-engineering-samples/tree/master/Samples_for_Extending_Pentaho/Reference%20Implementations/Security/SAML%202.0) (that extends the Spring SAML).

Right now I have declared multiple Service Providers (SPs) and Identity Providers (IDPs) in the blueprint.xml (one for each tenant plus a common SP). However at the end of the login flow I am not redirected to the home page but to a generic error page.

---

Here is an example of the blueprint.xml setup in the SAML Plugin:

```
  <bean id="spResourceFactoryCommon" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.sp.metadata.filesystem.common}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.sp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="spResourceFactoryTenant1" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.sp.metadata.filesystem.tenant1}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.sp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="spResourceFactoryTenant2" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.sp.metadata.filesystem.tenant2}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.sp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="idpResourceFactoryTenant1" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.idp.metadata.filesystem.tenant1}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.idp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="idpResourceFactoryTenant2" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.resources.MetadataResourceFactory">
    <argument>
      <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <entry key="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource" value="${saml.idp.metadata.filesystem.tenant2}" />
      </map>
    </argument>
    <argument value="${saml.idp.metadata.classpath.fallback}" />
  </bean>

  <!-- MetadataManager configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs and SP's  -->
  <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager" depends-on="pentahoSamlBootstrap">
    <argument>
      <list>
        <!-- sp metadata with extended metadata -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="spResourceFactoryCommon" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.incoming.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="pentahoCommon"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="spResourceFactoryTenant1" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.incoming.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant1sp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="spResourceFactoryTenant2" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.incoming.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant2sp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>

        <!-- idp metadata -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="idpResourceFactoryTenant1" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.response.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant1idp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
              <argument>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
              </argument>
              <argument>
                <bean factory-ref="idpResourceFactoryTenant2" factory-method="factoryResource" />
              </argument>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="${saml.discovery.idp.enabled}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.request.signed}"/>
              <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="${ensure.outgoing.logout.response.signed}"/>
              <property name="alias" value="tenant2idp"/>
              <property name="local" value="true"/>
            </bean>
          </argument>
        </bean>

      </list>
    </argument>
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager" />
    <property name="defaultIDP" value="${saml.idp.url}" />
  </bean>
```

With this configuration, when I go to the url
https://my.application.com/pentaho/alias/tenant1sp/sp?idp=tenant.1.name
I am redirected to the login page exposed by the IDP for the tenant1. After the login I am redirected to the previous url getting a generic error: [see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2um5G.png)

> Sorry, something went wrong.
> Please try again or contact
> your system administrator.

If I go to the URL https://my.application.com/pentaho/Home I am logged to the Pentaho dashboard. This makes me think that the login process has been successful but something went wrong with the redirect at the end of the flow. Indeed I would expect to be redirected to the URL https://my.application.com/pentaho/Home . **Can I configure this redirect somewhere/somehow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around seems to solve this issue, **however I see that it creates a conflict with the SAML authentication when using the exposed APIs of Pentaho. To use those APIs, this solution is not good.**

---

WORK AROUND

---

Change the *defaultTargetUrl* and *alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl* property of the *successRedirectHandler* bean (declared in the *blueprint.xml* file of the Pentaho-SAML Plugin)

```
  <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
  <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.PentahoSamlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
                        init-method="afterPropertiesSet">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="https://my.application.com/pentaho/Home"/>
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
    <property name="requireProxyWrapping" value="false"/>
  </bean>
```

---

Edit: Resolution ofAPIs login issue
I extended the *org.pentaho.platform.spring.security.saml.PentahoSamlAuthenticationSuccessHandler* class with a custom one that overrides the *onAuthenticationSuccess* method

```
private String contextPath;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
    
    //Apply the redirect to the Pentaho console Home if and only if the original targetUrl is not a Pentaho exposed API but the home (contextPath/Home)
    if (!savedRequest.getRedirectUrl().contains("API")
            && savedRequest.getRedirectUrl().contains(contextPath+"/Home")) {
        
        //The Pentaho console Home is set as defaultTargetUrl in the blueprint.xml
        this.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
        log.info("The request is not on a Pentaho API. Forcing the target URL to redirect to the defaultTargetUrl");
    }
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    
    //retore the original value of alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl
    this.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(false);
}
```